# How to iterate over a WeakMap?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, iterator, weakmap

A JavaScript [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) does not allow you to get the key, or the length or size, by design.

Is it possible to nevertheless loop over entries in some way ?

If not .. how does the Chrome console do this ?

[image]

Comment: No, weak maps are not iterable. The console does magic (hey, it shows the values of promises synchronously as well).

Comment: OK - I want to do that magic, any suggestions ? :-D

Comment: Write an application that uses the debug interface then :-)

Comment: the necessary functions are only available to privileged code. javascript executed in untrusted contexts cannot enumerate weak maps.

Comment: @bergi - thats actually a good idea, thanks :-)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Is it possible to nevertheless loop over entries in some way?

No, as you say, the contents of a `WeakMap` are not accessible by design, and there is no iterability.

> If not … how does the Chrome console do this?

The console uses the debugging API of the JS engine, which allows access to the internals of objects (also to promise states, wrapped primitives, etc.) and many more.

Comment: Ever since I read this answer, I started noticing more strange magic in the chrome console. There are rare situations where the console, when trying to trace code, can output data from the future, too :-)

Comment: @commonpike: That particular behaviour is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23392111/1048572).

Comment: Those look like values from the future relative to the past but not further than the present. :}

Answer (score 7):

Things are moving and it will soon be possible to create iterable week maps thanks to weak refs.
See the [iterable WeakMap example](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs#iterable-weakmaps) in the tc39 weakrefs proposal.

(note that it is already possible with nodejs v12.?.? using `--harmony-weak-refs` flag)

Answer (score -1):

Running far afield with a qualifier in your (2015) question, specifically:

> Is it possible to nevertheless loop over entries in some way ?

Yes.

In one ridiculous situation, it is possible to emulate and then iterate the keys and values of a WeakMap, and also to make a proper, independent copy of your WeakMap.

If the WeakMap you wish to clone was built in a very specific fashion by a constructor function, you can do it:

```
// Define a Constructor-Function
// that makes objects
// containing WeakMaps:
function makeWeakMapObject(){
  this.wm1 = new WeakMap();
  this.o1 = {};
  this.o2 = {"orange":"orange"};
  this.wm1.set(this.o1, 37);
  this.wm1.set(this.o2, 'azerty');
}

// Construct a new object:
let constructedWeakMapObject = new makeWeakMapObject();

// Then set a new key-value pair
// on the WeakMap in your object;
// because, ya know, otherwise you'd
// just reuse the WeakMap constructor
// and wouldn't need to clone :D
constructedWeakMapObject.added = {"ya":"glad"};
constructedWeakMapObject.wm1.set(constructedWeakMapObject.added, 42);


// In preparation to clone your newly constructed object,
// get that newly constructed object's property descriptors:
let props = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(constructedWeakMapObject);
// Have a gander at those props; just for fun:
console.log({"props":props});


// Attempt to clone the constructedWeakMapObject
// using its ownPropertyDescriptors
let weakClone = new cloneWeak(props);
// and then check out what you made:
console.log({"weakClone":weakClone});


// Verify that you've made an independent clone
// (even though this example is shallow)
// by altering the WeakMap in your weakClone:
weakClone.wm.delete(weakClone.o1);
// Make sure your clone was altered:
console.log(weakClone.wm.get(weakClone.o1));

// And then check to see that the
// changes to your clone 
// don't appear on your constructed object:
console.log(constructedWeakMapObject);
console.log(constructedWeakMapObject.wm1.get(constructedWeakMapObject.o1));

// A support function to help you use fresh keys in your cloned WeakMap to keep it independent from your original WeakMap
function cloneObject(obj) { // use something more robust, like underscore: _.cloneDeep(obj); actually, you'll likely have to roll your own so you can make clones of functions... anywho
    var clone = {};
    for(var i in obj) {
        if(typeof(obj[i])==="object" && obj[i] !== null)
            clone[i] = cloneObject(obj[i]);
        else
            clone[i] = obj[i];
    }
    return clone;
}

// Called as a constructor function w/arguments
function cloneWeak(inco){ // a bit wonky, at least in the middle
  
  this.wm = new WeakMap();

  let tempMap;
  
  for(key in inco){
    // Build keys on 'this' that match the incoming keys
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(inco[key].value) !== "[object WeakMap]"){
    
        this[key] = cloneObject(inco[key].value);
    }
    // Reference the incoming map from your temp map
    // (this makes the following loop possible)
    else{tempMap = inco[key].value;}
  }
  
  this.fakeForHack = {}; // no idea why this works
  this.wm.set(this.fakeForHack, "ok"); // no idea why this works... without it, the WeakMap entry for made.wm1.get(made.added) won't transfer -> ???
  
  for(key in inco){
    
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(inco[key].value) !== "[object WeakMap]"){
      // Set values for 'this' WeakMap:
      this.wm.set(this[key], tempMap.get(inco[key].value));
    }
  }
}
```

It's kinda ugly, it's brittle, and it only solves a ridiculous edge-case; you're welcome!