# Uncaught TypeError: weakMap.forEach is not a function()

Tags: javascript

I'm exploring the new ES6 feature: the `WeakMap`. I'm starting with the basic example I found on MDN.

The issue I have is that I can't loop over the WeakMap elements. I got the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: weakMap.forEach is not a function

Below is my simple example I created:

```js
var myWeakMap = new WeakMap();
myWeakMap.set({a: 1}, 11);
myWeakMap.set({b: 2}, 22);
myWeakMap.set({c: 3}, 33);

myWeakMap.forEach(function (item, key, myWeakMapObject) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

How can I loop over all elements?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32543187/2545680

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a weakmap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402837/how-to-iterate-over-a-weakmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this `myWeakMap` is an empty Object

```js
var myWeakMap = new WeakMap();
myWeakMap.set({a: 1}, 11);
myWeakMap.set({b: 2}, 22);
myWeakMap.set({c: 3}, 33);
console.log(myWeakMap);
```