# Truly Weak Reference Event Emitter / Dispatcher: is it possible?

Tags: javascript, events, weak-references, eventemitter, weakmap

I was wondering if truly weak reference event dispatcher / emitter mechanism is possible to be implemented in JS at the current level of development of the JS technology?

Yesterday I took a very popular eventemitter3 lib and changed it a bit to use WeakMap for saving references to listeners. But today, at the morning, I realized that actually it wouldn't work as, for example, it used to work in AS 3.0 (hey, FLASH fans!), because references to listeners would live as long as the dispatcher itself would live.

```js
'use strict';

var has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty
    , prefix = '~';

/**
 * Constructor to create a storage for our `EE` objects.
 * An `Events` instance is a plain object whose properties are event names.
 *
 * @constructor
 * @private
 */
function Events() {
}

//
// We try to not inherit from `Object.prototype`. In some engines creating an
// instance in this way is faster than calling `Object.create(null)` directly.
// If `Object.create(null)` is not supported we prefix the event names with a
// character to make sure that the built-in object properties are not
// overridden or used as an attack vector.
//
if (Object.create) {
    Events.prototype = Object.create(null);

    //
    // This hack is needed because the `__proto__` property is still inherited in
    // some old browsers like Android 4, iPhone 5.1, Opera 11 and Safari 5.
    //
    if (!new Events().__proto__) prefix = false;
}

/**
 * Representation of a single event listener.
 *
 * @param {Function} fn The listener function.
 * @param {*} context The context to invoke the listener with.
 * @param {Boolean} [once=false] Specify if the listener is a one-time listener.
 * @constructor
 * @private
 */
function EE(fn, context, once) {
    this.fn = fn;
    this.context = context;
    this.once = once || false;
}

/**
 * Add a listener for a given event.
 *
 * @param {WeakEventEmitter} emitter Reference to the `WeakEventEmitter` instance.
 * @param {(String|Symbol)} event The event name.
 * @param {Function} fn The listener function.
 * @param {*} context The context to invoke the listener with.
 * @param {Boolean} once Specify if the listener is a one-time listener.
 * @returns {WeakEventEmitter}
 * @private
 */
function addListener(emitter, event, fn, context, once) {
    if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('The listener must be a function');
    }

    var listener = new EE(fn, context || emitter, once)
        , evt = prefix ? prefix + event : event;

    var _events = emitter._weakMap.get(emitter);
    if (!_events[evt]) _events[evt] = listener, emitter._eventsCount++;
    else if (!_events[evt].fn) _events[evt].push(listener);
    else _events[evt] = [_events[evt], listener];

    return emitter;
}

/**
 * Clear event by name.
 *
 * @param {WeakEventEmitter} emitter Reference to the `WeakEventEmitter` instance.
 * @param {(String|Symbol)} evt The Event name.
 * @private
 */
function clearEvent(emitter, evt) {
    if (--emitter._eventsCount === 0) {
        emitter._weakMap.set(emitter, new Events());

    } else {
        var _events = emitter._weakMap.get(emitter);
        delete _events[evt];
    }
}

/**
 * Minimal `WeakEventEmitter` interface that is molded against the Node.js
 * `WeakEventEmitter` interface.
 *
 * @constructor
 * @public
 */
function WeakEventEmitter() {
    this._weakMap = new WeakMap();
    this._weakMap.set(this, new Events());

    this._eventsCount = 0;
}

/**
 * Return an array listing the events for which the emitter has registered
 * listeners.
 *
 * @returns {Array}
 * @public
 */
WeakEventEmitter.prototype.eventNames = function eventNames() {
    var names = []
        , events
        , name;

    if (this._eventsCount === 0) return names;

    var _events = this._weakMap.get(this);
    for (name in (events = _events)) {
        if (has.call(events, name)) names.push(prefix ? name.slice(1) : name);
    }

    if (Object.getOwnPropertySymbols) {
        return names.concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(events));
    }

    return names;
};

/**
 * Return the listeners registered for a given event.
 *
 * @param {(String|Symbol)} event The event name.
 * @returns {Array} The registered listeners.
 * @public
 */
WeakEventEmitter.prototype.listeners = function listeners(event) {
    var _events = this._weakMap.get(this);

    var evt = prefix ? prefix + event : event
        , handlers = _events[evt];

    if (!handlers) return [];
    if (handlers.fn) return [handlers.fn];

    for (var i = 0, l = handlers.length, ee = new Array(l); i < l; i++) {
        ee[i] = handlers[i].fn;
    }

    return ee;
};

/**
 * Return the number of listeners listening to a given event.
 *
 * @param {(String|Symbol)} event The event name.
 * @returns {Number} The number of listeners.
 * @public
 */
WeakEventEmitter.prototype.listenerCount = function listenerCount(event) {
    var _events = this._weakMap.get(this);

    var evt = prefix ? prefix + event : event
        , listeners = _events[evt];

    if (!listeners) return 0;
    if (listeners.fn) return 1;
    return listeners.length;
};

/**
 * Calls each of the listeners registered for a given event.
 *
 * @param {(String|Symbol)} event The event name.
 * @returns {Boolean} `true` if the event had listeners, else `false`.
 * @public
 */
WeakEventEmitter.prototype.emit = function emit(event, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) {
    var evt = prefix ? prefix + event : event;

    var _events = this._weakMap.get(this);
    if (!_events[evt]) return false;

    var listeners = _events[evt]
        , len = arguments.length
        , args
        , i;

    if (listeners.fn) {
        if (listeners.once) this.removeListener(event, listeners.fn, undefined, true);

        switch (len) {
            case 1:
                return listeners.fn.call(listeners.context), true;
            case 2:
                return listeners.fn.call(listeners.context, a1), true;
            case 3:
                return listeners.fn.call(listeners.context, a1, a2), true;
            case 4:
                return listeners.fn.call(listeners.context, a1, a2, a3), true;
            case 5:
                return listeners.fn.call(listeners.context, a1, a2, a3, a4), true;
            case 6:
                return listeners.fn.call(listeners.context, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5), true;
        }

        for (i = 1, args = new Array(len - 1); i < len; i++) {
            args[i - 1] = arguments[i];
        }

        listeners.fn.apply(listeners.context, args);
    } else {
        var length = listeners.length
            , j;

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (listeners[i].once) this.removeListener(event, listeners[i].fn, undefined, true);

            switch (len) {
                case 1:
                    listeners[i].fn.call(listeners[i].context);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    listeners[i].fn.call(listeners[i].context, a1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    listeners[i].fn.call(listeners[i].context, a1, a2);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    listeners[i].fn.call(listeners[i].context, a1, a2, a3);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (!args) for (j = 1, args = new Array(len - 1); j < len; j++) {
                        args[j - 1] = arguments[j];
                    }

                    listeners[i].fn.apply(listeners[i].context, args);
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
};

/**
 * Add a listener for a given event.
 *
 * @param {(String|Symbol)} event The event name.
 * @param {Function} fn The listener function.
 * @param {*} [context=this] The context to invoke the listener with.
 * @returns {WeakEventEmitter} `this`.
 * @public
 */
WeakEventEmitter.prototype.on = function on(event, fn, context) {
    return addListener(this, event, fn, context, false);
};

/**
 * Add a one-time listener for a given event.
 *
 * @param {(String|Symbol)} event The event name.
 * @param {Function} fn The listener function.
 * @param {*} [context=this] The context to invoke the listener with.
 * @returns {WeakEventEmitter} `this`.
 * @public
 */
WeakEventEmitter.prototype.once = function once(event, fn, context) {
    return addListener(this, event, fn, context, true);
};

/**
 * Remove the listeners of a given event.
 *
 * @param {(String|Symbol)} event The event name.
 * @param {Function} fn Only remove the listeners that match this function.
 * @param {*} context Only remove the listeners that have this context.
 * @param {Boolean} once Only remove one-time listeners.
 * @returns {WeakEventEmitter} `this`.
 * @public
 */
WeakEventEmitter.prototype.removeListener = function removeListener(event, fn, context, once) {
    var evt = prefix ? prefix + event : event;

    var _events = this._weakMap.get(this);
    if (!_events[evt]) return this;
    if (!fn) {
        clearEvent(this, evt);
        return this;
    }

    var listeners = _events[evt];

    if (listeners.fn) {
        if (
            listeners.fn === fn &&
            (!once || listeners.once) &&
            (!context || listeners.context === context)
        ) {
            clearEvent(this, evt);
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0, events = [], length = listeners.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (
                listeners[i].fn !== fn ||
                (once && !listeners[i].once) ||
                (context && listeners[i].context !== context)
            ) {
                events.push(listeners[i]);
            }
        }

        //
        // Reset the array, or remove it completely if we have no more listeners.
        //
        var _events = this._weakMap.get(this);
        if (events.length) _events[evt] = events.length === 1 ? events[0] : events;
        else clearEvent(this, evt);
    }

    return this;
};

/**
 * Remove all listeners, or those of the specified event.
 *
 * @param {(String|Symbol)} [event] The event name.
 * @returns {WeakEventEmitter} `this`.
 * @public
 */
WeakEventEmitter.prototype.removeAllListeners = function removeAllListeners(event) {
    var evt;

    if (event) {
        evt = prefix ? prefix + event : event;
        var _events = this._weakMap.get(this);
        if (_events[evt]) clearEvent(this, evt);

    } else {
        this._weakMap.set(this, new Events());
        this._eventsCount = 0;
    }

    return this;
};

//
// Alias methods names because people roll like that.
//
WeakEventEmitter.prototype.off = WeakEventEmitter.prototype.removeListener;
WeakEventEmitter.prototype.addListener = WeakEventEmitter.prototype.on;

//
// Expose the prefix.
//
WeakEventEmitter.prefixed = prefix;

//
// Allow `WeakEventEmitter` to be imported as module namespace.
//
WeakEventEmitter.WeakEventEmitter = WeakEventEmitter;

//
// Expose the module.
//
if ('undefined' !== typeof module) {
    module.exports = WeakEventEmitter;
}
```

Would really appreciate any help!

P.S.: any, and I mean it, ANT help is very appreciated. If somebody explains why this is not technically possible today, it would be as valuable as giving clues about possible implementation of the weak-reference event dispatcher mechanism.

Comment: A bit tired rn, but isn't the native EventTarget interface doing this already?

Comment: @Kaiido, as far as I see there is no mention of weak references: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget

Comment: Why would there be any? What about you describe these "some cases, which are currently not possible to use in JS, because of lack of weak-reference dispatchers.”

Comment: @Kaiido, I'm sorry, but either I didn't understand you correctly, or you didn't understand correctly me.

The main purpose of the question to figure out whether truly weak-reference event dispatcher mechanism is possible in JS today. You mentioned the EventTarget class saying that it might already does what I described, but it seems that it doesn't. Are there any other reasons why you mentioned the EventTarget class?

Comment: @Kaiido, one of the cases (and actually it's a primary one):
1) adding listener
2) remove the object who "listens" the event, without removing the listener
3) don't worry about memory leaks and other stuff, because weak-ref mechanism wouldn't keep the object in memory, even if you don't remove listener by yourself

Comment: Not sure to get your case. Lets say, object *A* triggers an event "foo", then you want that object *B* listens for *A*'s "foo" event. Now if *B* gets unreferenced its listener callback gets garbage collected too? I first understood the other way around: that if *A* is removed all the attached listeners should become garbage, which is the what EventTarget does. For the former case, you'd need [WeakRef](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs/blob/master/README.md), since WeakMap are not iterable, but I think it's still hidden under browsers flags.

Comment: @Kaiido, yeap, you described perfectly the case I was thinking about. Thanks for the WeakRef link, I haven't heard about it.

Comment: @Kaiido, if you create and answer based on your last comment (e.g. weakref event dispatcher mechanism is not possible now, but will be possible when the WeakRef class is released), I would love to give you the bounty (if there would be no better answers or clues to the problem).

Answer (score 4):

Let me first rephrase your question so my answer be clearer.

- You want an event emitter `[Emitter]` to trigger an event *foo-event*.
- You want an object `[observer]`, to attach an event handler `handler`, for when `[Emitter]` fires its *foo-event*.
- You want that when all references to `[observer]` are broken, `handler` becomes garbage collectable as well.

---

What you made here with your WeakMap is actually the behavior of the built-in EventTarget:

When `[Emitter]` becomes collectable, `handler` also becomes.
`[observer]` is irrelevant.

For what you want, you would have had to use that `[observer]` object as the WeakMap's key (`WeakMap.set( observer, handler )`), so that when `[observer]` is unlinked, it's no more in the WeakMap.
But [WeakMaps are not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402837/how-to-iterate-over-a-weakmap), so that won't work...

---

What you need are [`WeakRef`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs/blob/master/README.md#iterable-weakmaps), but these are still as of this writing a proposal (stage 3) and hidden under experimental flags in major browsers [ref](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs/blob/master/README.md#status).

With it enabled, you could have used something like this [IterableWeakMap](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs/blob/master/README.md#iterable-weakmaps) to store your observers.

```js
addObserver( event_type, observer, handler ) {
  // this._events = Map { 'foo-event' -> IterableWeakMap }
  const iterableWeakMap = this._events.get( event_type );
  iterableWeakMap.set( observer, handler );
}
triggerEvent( event_type ) {
  const evt = {/* */};
  const iterableWeakMap = this._events.get( event_type );
  for( const [ observer, handler ] of iterableWeakMap ) {
    handler( evt );
  }
}
```

Comment: "What you made here with your WeakMap is actually the behavior of the built-in EventTarget:"

Do you have a source for this? I checked MDN but didn't see anything about this.